# Sensor Error Adjustment

Tags: sensor, error, compensation

I have been asked to improve the high end accuracy of a pressure sensor (Without modifying hardware). I have collected data from 30 samples and found a trend to the error. My question now is if it is possible using only this data to come up with a compensation equation that I can apply to real time measurements to remove the high end inaccuracy.

My first thought was to find a curve fit of the average error and apply that to new measurements but I didn't see as much improvement as I had expected.

Other ideas or recommendations would be appreciated.

[image: Error vs Applied Pressure]

Comment: It would help if you told us what the pressure sensor was, what the range you have is, and what you are measuring it with...

Comment: When you plot this average error in the same graph, you can see the deviation from this average increases with higher pressure. Using this average and deviation knowledge, you need to take several measurements for a given pressure to determine the real value. The number of samples depends where you estimate your sample measurement is: at which pressure. That's my common sense: there definitely most be a scientific/mathematic approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can calibrate the sensors with a measurement at x=170 using a power exponent to the interpolate the curve.  Other errors may be due to hysteresis, loose connections or noise.

I plotted the average to be \$y(x)=-0.0000656*x^{2.573}, R^2=0.995\$

But better results can be obtained curve-fitting with 2 or more measurements.